# NSMutableArray adding elements get overwritten in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to add elements to an `NSMutableArray` whenever a user selects a country. But each time I use `[myarray setobject:@""];`, it's adding the new value, overwriting my old value. I want this array as I'm using it in:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:(NSMutableArray *)selectedCountriesByUser forKey:@"userSelection"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```

I want an array which maintains the list of countries selected by the user even after the application is closed.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

`setObject` replace all objects in array

for example, get value from `NSUserDefault`:

```
NSMutableArray *myMutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefault standardUserDefault] objectForKey:"userSelection"]];
```

you should use   `[myMutableArray addObject:"aCountry"];`  without overwriting, but adding only

and after

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:myMutableArray forKey:@"userSelection"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```

**EDIT:**

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {

   //your selectedCountriesByUser
   myMutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefault standardUserDefault] objectForKey:"userSelection"]];

 }

...

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

     //add object to array
     [myMutableArray adObject:"yourObj"];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:myMutableArray forKey:@"userSelection"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];

 }
```

Comment: Tried with [myMutableArray addObject:"aCountry"];this is also overwriting my method.In viewdidload i'm allocating it.myMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; Each time when i come from previous view to current view this method will run..Is this the reason for overwriting my array?If so how can i make my array to save  with all the countries selected by user.

Comment: you retrieve value from nsuserDefault like my code? every time in your viewDidLoad you must do like my code, so you fill in your array the stored values

Comment: This is what my application is about:List of countries displays in tableview.So i'll get which country is selected only in -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath.I want the selected country to be stored in an array later it can be used in NSUserDefault.

Comment: This is what i've done in my code:In viewdidload :   selectedCountriesByUser = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];and in -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   [selectedCountriesByUser addObject:selectedCountry];[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:(NSMutableArray *)selectedCountriesByUser forKey:@"userSelection"];    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
    myArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"userSelection"];
    NSLog(@"array count in viewcontroller %d",[myArray count]);

Comment: i'm getting exception as "[__NSCFNumber count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb660ef0" at line  :   selectedCountriesByUser = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"userSelection"]];

Comment: @user3162102 have you changed with this?:     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:selectedCountriesByUser forKey:@"userSelection"];

Comment: -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
[selectedCountriesByUser addObject:selectedCountry];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:selectedCountriesByUser forKey:@"userSelection"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
    
    myArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"userSelection"];
    NSLog(@"array count in viewcontroller %d",[myArray count]); this is what i've done

Comment: and in viewdidload:i've done the same way as u've told like:selectedCountriesByUser = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"userSelection"]];

Comment: @user3162102 what is myArray? why you fill values in it?

Comment: Sir i'm saving the values using NSUserdefaults and just to check the values are properly saved or not i'm retrieving it back using myArray and displaying the count to see how many countries are added.But exception is in different line

Comment: @user3162102 ok.. try selectedCountriesByUser = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; selectedCountriesByUser = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"userSelection"]];

Answer (score 0):

You're asking two different things. First, `-setObject:` is not a NS(Mutable)Array method. You are probably looking for the `-addObject:` method. So, to add an object to your NSMutableArray, you need to do:

```
[myMutableArray addObject:yourObject] 
//Remember that `-addObject` is present only in NSMutableArray, not in NSArray
```

The second thing you are trying to achieve is to store the array in NSUserDefaults. to do so, after you add the object to the array you want, you should be fine do to so:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:myMutableArray forKey:@"userSelection"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// ARRAY DECLARATION AND ASSIGNMENT OF VALUES TO IT    

NSMutableArray * selectedCountriesByUserArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[selectedCountriesByUserArray addObject:@"value1"];
[selectedCountriesByUserArray addObject:@"value2"];
[selectedCountriesByUserArray addObject:@"value3"];

// STORING AN ARRAY WITH THE KEY "userSelection" USING NSUSERDEFAULTS

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:selectedCountriesByUserArray forKey:@"userSelection"];
[defaults synchronize];
```